# How can I use a parameter out of function in python?

Tags: python, parameters

I'm new to python.I wrote the code like below.

```
page_number = 1
```

I defined a parameter in the class.

```
def begin():
    answer = raw_input("continue?")
    if answer == 'q':
        exit()
    else:
        page_number += 1
```

But when I access it like above ,it goes wrong.
I'm wondering how can I get it in this function.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [You need to use `global page_number` at the top of the function](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

Comment: I don't see a parameter (apart of `raw_input` one), nor a class. Please post the complete code. Also, if you are getting an error, post the stack trace.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks very much. I solved this problem as you said.

Comment: @Christian Thank you ,I've solved this problem. I will be careful in next question.

Comment: Just remember to read about parameters. It seems like you are a bit confused about that.

Comment: @Christian ok ,can I call it attribute or field ?Actually,I don't know how to distinguish them.

Comment: @Brutal_JL You can call it a variable, and inside a class it is called an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
def begin(answer): 
    page_number = 1
```

it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need `global` keyword.

```
def begin():
    global page_number
    answer = raw_input("continue?")
    if answer == 'q':
        exit()
    else:
        page_number += 1
```